# How to interact with a REST service in C#

Tags: c#, json, rest

I'm developing a small application that has to interact with a JSON/REST service.
What is the easiest option to interact with it in my c# application.

I don't need to have the best performances, since it's just a tools that will do some synchronization once a day, I'm more oriented toward the ease of use and the time of development.

(the service in question will be our local JIRA instance).

Comment: This is primarily opinion based and asking for framework recommendations. Both are off-topic.

Comment: ? I don't ask for any framework, just how to do it

Comment: You would think a member of 6 years; top 6%; ~4500 rep would know how to _ask a good question_?

Comment: Don't you think "how do I interact with it" implies asking for a framework or tool to use to perform the interaction? Do you think it's opinion based because you say "What is the easiest?" Do you think it's too broad, because your question isn't specific and is about a broad topic with many possible answers? Stack Overflow is for answering specific programming problems. Pick a framework, decide on how to implement it. If you get stuck with implementing your code, *then* you would have a valid topic to ask about. You've been on SO long enough, set a good example for others.

Comment: @mason I just want to know the options to do it, if there is builtin solutions(like reference remote service in Visual Studio)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the best way by far is to use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). It's a free Nuget Package that you can reference. It's very easy to use and this is the example from their website:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
// client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); // replaces matching token in request.Resource

// easily add HTTP Headers
request.AddHeader("header", "value");

// add files to upload (works with compatible verbs)
request.AddFile(path);

// execute the request
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

// or automatically deserialize result
// return content type is sniffed but can be explicitly set via RestClient.AddHandler();
RestResponse<Person> response2 = client.Execute<Person>(request);
var name = response2.Data.Name;

// easy async support
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
});

// async with deserialization
var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<Person>(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Data.Name);
});

// abort the request on demand
asyncHandle.Abort();
```